# Django ORM and left join - through annotate?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
Asset.objects.filter(
            campaigns__games__pk=_version.game_id,
            campaigns__is_active=True,
            campaigns__games__active=True,
            is_active=True).select_related('org').all()
```

this query returns 49 records

```
Asset.objects.filter(
            campaigns__games__pk=_version.game_id,
            campaigns__is_active=True,
            campaigns__games__active=True,
            is_active=True,
            coupons__session__device_id='GUID').select_related('org').all()
```

only **ONE**, because it makes INNER JOIN to Asset.coupons.session table.
In reality what I want to retrieve the same 49 records as in the first query, but with additional information from session table if it exists.

So I want to achieve is LEFT JOIN, so if for given asset the session exist - I then set a flag 'is_saved=True' in my API response.

As far as I understand - the correct way is to use **Annotate** or **Case/When**?

**How to achieve?**

Comment: Cann you post your models?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're asking the ORM to return `Asset`s that have a `Session` with the `device_id` field set to `GUID`, so this is definitely an `INNER JOIN` - a `Session` must exist for a given `Asset` in order for you to be able to query a field on it.

You should be able to achieve what you need using:

```py
Asset.objects.filter(
    campaigns__games__pk=_version.game_id,
    campaigns__is_active=True,
    campaigns__games__active=True,
    is_active=True,
).annotate(
    session__device_id=F('coupons__session__device_id')
    # any other fields can go here
).select_related(
    'org'
).all()
```

Or if you're only after a boolean `True` if `coupons__session` is not NULL, you should be fine using [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries).